# Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли разделила на слоги? и если не трудно объясните...

Tags: фонетика

во-схи-ще-ни-е кра-са-той зем-ли, где жи-ли де-ды и пра-де-ды где нам су-жде-но про-жить жизнь, по-вто-рить се-бя в де-тях со-ста-ри-ться и уй-ти в зе-млю, ро-ди-вшу-ю нас-это ва-жней-ший э-мо-ци-о-наль-ный и-сто-чник лю-бви к Ро-ди-не.

Comment: орфографическая ошибка: кра-сО-той

Comment: и запятых не хватает

Answer (score 1):

во-схи-ще-ни-е кра-со-той зе-мли, где жи-ли де-ды и пра-де-ды, где нам су-жде-но про-жить жизнь, по-вто-рить[фто] се-бя в де-тях со-ста-ри-ться[ца] и уй-ти в зе-млю, ро-ди-вшу-ю [фшу]нас-это ва-жней-ший э-мо-ци-о-на-льный и-сто-чник лю-бви к Ро-ди-не.

Всё верно, кроме зе-мли, э-мо-ци-о-на-льный: Сочетание сонорных согласных между гласными отходит к последующему слогу.

Слог как основная звуковая единица русского языка строится по закону восходящей звучности: в пределах слога звуки располагаются от наименее звучного к наиболее звучному. Слогораздел проходит в месте наибольшего спада звучности. Наиболее звучными являются гласные (Г), затем в порядке уменьшающейся звучности идут сонорные (С), затем шумные (Ш) согласные. Отсюда следует несколько правил деления слов на фонетические слоги.

1. Г—ШШГ
   Сочетание шумных согласных между гласными отходит к последующему слогу:про-стой, зве-зда, ло-дка.
2. Г—ШСГ
   Сочетание шумного согласного с сонорным между гласными отходит к последующему слогу: до-бро, ве-сло, до-гма.
3. ГС—ШГ
   Сочетание сонорного согласного с шумным между гласными имеет слогораздел внутри этого сочетания: пар-та, кол-ба, лом-кий, брон-за.
4. Гj—ШГ, Гj—СГ
   Сочетание звука [j] с шумным или сонорным между гласными имеет слогораздел внутри этого сочетания: лей-ка, вой-дём, кай-ма, сай-ра.
5. Г—ССГ
   Сочетание сонорных согласных между гласными отходит к последующему слогу:ко-рма, то-мный

Comment: Забыли еще слово *это* поделить на слоги : э-то...

Comment: Верно! Я не заметила.

Comment: Значит, пофиксили старые правила - делить по частям слова?
Например, "во-схи-ще-ни-е". Мне больше "вос-хи-ще-ни-е" нравилось...

Comment: Может, Вы путаете с делением для переноса? Мы говорим о фонетическом слоге. Здесь правила не менялись, всегда такие были. В школе когда-то о фонетическом слоге вообще не говорилось, а вот сейчас даже в 1 классе изучают, и я считаю это правильным.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Мне нужны именно для переноса. А то на одном форуме встретил человека, который приведенную систему для переноса рекомендовал, и остался в недоумении.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже немного удивлена, что деление на слоги: во-схи-ще-ни-е, зе-мли, су-ждено, 
ро-ди-вшу-ю и так далее)))) Сама бы разделила вос-хи-щение, зем-ли, ро-див-шу-ю (в слове ро-ди-вшу-ю, слог -вшу- не понравился как-то, после этого заметила и другие аналогичные слоги). А ведь пятёрочницей была в школе! :)

Comment: Видимо, Вы тоже учились в советские времена, когда о фонетическом слоге не слышали.Помнится, нам и о транскрипции ничего не говорили,я  о ней услышала в институте. А сейчас ещё и фонематическая транскрипция,надо бы изучить и её, но как-то руки не доходят, нет надобности. Пусть студенты учат.

Comment: Людмила, большое спасибо вам!